# Exc Bad Access while unarchiving data from iCloud using UIDocument

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, nskeyedarchiver, uidocument

Hi i am using iCloud support for my application and using `UIDocument` for storage. I was able to save data to iCloud and fetch the same for first time. But when i deleted and reinstalled the app on device, the seems to crash with `EXC BAD ACCESS` while trying to unarchive data using `NSKeyUnarchiver`.

Code.

```
BuyerDocument.m // UIDocument Subclass

// Accessor for BuyerData

- (BuyerData *)data {
if (_data == nil) {
    if (self.fileWrapper != nil) {
        self.data = [self decodeObjectFromWrapperWithPreferredFilename:BUYER_FILENAME];  // BUYER_FILENAME = @"buyer.data"
    } else {
        self.data = [[BuyerData alloc] init];
    }
}
return _data;
}

- (id)decodeObjectFromWrapperWithPreferredFilename:(NSString *)preferredFilename {

NSFileWrapper * fileWrapper = [self.fileWrapper.fileWrappers objectForKey:preferredFilename];
if (!fileWrapper) {
    NSLog(@"Unexpected error: Couldn't find %@ in file wrapper!", preferredFilename);
    return nil;
}
if([fileWrapper isRegularFile]){
    NSLog(@"is regular wrapper");
}
NSData * data = [fileWrapper regularFileContents];

NSLog(@"data %@",data);         // This logs successfully
//    NSLog(@"data bytes %@",[data bytes])     // This also causes app to crash.
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];       // App will crash here

return [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"data"];
}
```

Loading BuyerDocument here.

```
- (void)loadDocAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL {

// Open doc so we can read metadata
BuyerDocument * doc = [[BuyerDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:fileURL];
[doc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
.......
    BuyerData * data = doc.data;

    ....
    [doc closeWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

       .....          
}];
}


 BuyerData.m

#define kVersionKey @"Version"
#define kNameKey @"Name"

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
   [encoder encodeInt:1 forKey:kVersionKey];
   [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:kNameKey];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
[decoder decodeIntForKey:kVersionKey];
NSString *nameData = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kNameKey];
//    NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> %@",name);   // This logs for first 2-3 files and then crash occurs
return [self initWithName:nameData];
}
```

As i said when i first added data everything ran fine, it was only after deleting and reinstalling that crash began to occur. Also first 3-4 names are fetched and displayed in tableview before this crash occurs.
Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903119/uidocument-loadfromcontents-fails-with-exc-bad-access) but of no help
I am fairly new to `UIDocument` and `NSCoding`. So can't say much about them. But i guess some how the issue might be with linked to `NSData` getting lost or corrupted out there. Am i missing something basic and important here. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXC\_BAD\_ACCESS using iCloud on multiple devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743517/exc-bad-access-using-icloud-on-multiple-devices)

Comment: @Kerni: Thanks. I was able to solve the issue, strangely, by deleting my iCloud account from device,adding it and then reinstalling app again on all devices. for now its working fine on all device